Creating a list in JS via selected cheboxes values
I want to store the value of several checkboxes (URLs) in a JS variable, and I want the list to be updated every time a box is checked or unchecked. However I cannot console.log anything and when I check I have a message "updateSelectedImageURLs (this is my function) is not defined". Do you have an idea why ?
This is my checkbox:
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="crop_checkbox" 
    value="{{ img_file|img_to_iiif:small }}"
    onchange="updateSelectedImageURLs()">

This is my JS
// Sélectionnez toutes les cases à cocher
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="crop_checkbox"]');
var selectedImageURLs = [];
// Fonction pour mettre à jour la liste des URL sélectionnées
function updateSelectedImageURLs() {
    // Réinitialiser la liste des URL sélectionnées
    selectedImageURLs = [];

    // Parcourir toutes les cases à cocher
    checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
        // Vérifier si la case est cochée
        if (checkbox.checked) {
            // Récupérez l'URL de l'image à partir de la value de la case cochée
            var imageURL = checkbox.value;

            // Ajouter l'URL de l'image à la liste des URL sélectionnées
            selectedImageURLs.push(imageURL);
            }
        }
    );

    // Afficher la liste des URL sélectionnées
    console.log(selectedImageURLs);
}

// Ajouter un écouteur d'événements à chaque case à cocher
//checkboxes.forEach(function(checkbox) {
    //checkbox.addEventListener('change', updateSelectedImageURLs);
//});

// Appel pour mettre à jour
//updateSelectedImageURLs();

// hidden input
document.getElementById("listeURL").value = selectedImageURLs;

//switch views

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('toggleBtn');
    const view1 = document.getElementById('view1');
    const view2 = document.getElementById('view2');

    toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Vérifie si la première vue est visible
        const isView1Visible = !view1.classList.contains('hidden');
        
        // Si la première vue est visible, la cache et affiche la deuxième vue
        if (isView1Visible) {
            view1.classList.add('hidden');
            view2.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else { // Sinon, affiche la première vue et cache la deuxième vue
            view1.classList.remove('hidden');
            view2.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    });


});

It is enveloped in an event listener "DOMContentLoaded" with the rest of my script for the page.
Thank you so much if you have an idea?

updateSelectedImageURLs is not defined likely/generally means that the function is out of scope from where you are calling it.   eg if the function definition is defined in DOMContentLoaded callback but you are calling it from elsewhere (eg onchange=). edit can see that now, it was scrolled across.   Move the function updateSelectedImageURLs { .. } code to outside the DOMContentLoaded callback (so it's at the window level)

Thanks so much for your answer, you are right I don't have an error message anymore, however I still cannot consol.log my var selectedImegeULRs : the consol eanswers undefined

provide full details of your code. As @fdomn-m said, it must be not able to access the updateSelectedImageURLs function||
update, again from where you are calling selectedImegeULRs is out of scope of selectedImegeULRs

I updated with the whole js but there is not much more

https://jsfiddle.net/53mkyrfc/ proves that the basic parts of your code should work fine. Are you still not getting anything logged to the console? Or is maybe just the end result of the whole process not the expected one - because document.getElementById("listeURL").value = selectedImageURLs; should also be moved into the updateSelectedImageURLs function, perhaps?

Still nothing logged. The updated list should then be send to the hidden input of a button. For the moment nothing is sent.

The updated list should then be send to the hidden input of a button - it only does this when you tell it to.  In your updated code, you tell it once, when the page is loaded.  Move document.getElementById("listeURL").value = selectedImageURLs; to inside function updateSelectedImageURLs() {

Thanks a lot for your help, however I still have that problem of nothing being logged and my variable remaining undefined. So strange...
